# do not issue an error if no image is set

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make this page that edits a post, now i don't want it to issue an error if no image is set, because an image might have been set already, what am i missing here?

```
<?php
// Checks if post id is set else don't proceed
if (isset($_GET['postId'])) {
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
        $required_fields = array('title', 'content', 'excerpt');
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
      if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
         $errors[] = 'جميع الحقول مطلوبة';
         break 1;
      }
   }
}
    if (isset($_FILES['bigthumb'], $_FILES['smallthumb'])) {
        $bigThumbTmp = $_FILES['bigthumb']['tmp_name'];
        $bigThumbName = $_FILES['bigthumb']['name'];
        $smallThumbTmp = $_FILES['smallthumb']['tmp_name'];
        $smallThumpName = $_FILES['smallthumb']['name'];
        //try {
        $smallthumb_dir = upload_image($smallThumbTmp,$smallThumpName);
        $bigthumb_dir   = upload_image($bigThumbTmp,$bigThumbName);
        /*} catch (ErrorException $e) {
            die('No image uploading');
        }*/
    }

if (isset($_GET['addPostSuccess']) === true && empty($_GET['addPostSuccess']) === false) {
    echo 'تم تعديل المقالة!';
}
    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
        $postId = $_GET['postId'];
        $postData = array(
            'important'     => $_POST['important'],
            'vis'           => $_POST['vis'],
            'cat_id'        => $_POST['cat_id'],
            'user_id'       => $_POST['user_id'],
            'bigthumb'      => addslashes($bigthumb_dir),
            'smallthumb'    => addslashes($smallthumb_dir),
            'title'         => addslashes($_POST['title']),
            'content'       => addslashes($_POST['content']),
            'excerpt'       => addslashes($_POST['excerpt'])
            );

            edit_post($postId, $postData);
            die(header('Location: index.php?p=posts&postEditSuccess'));
            //exit();
    } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
    ?>


<h1>تعديل مقالة</h1>

<h4>تذكر جميع الحقول مطلوبة</h4>

    <form action="" method="post" name="editPost" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <ul>
            <li>
                عنوان المقالة:<br>
                <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php get_title($postId); ?>">
            </li>
            <li>
            مقالة مهمة:<br>
            <select name="important">
                <?php   if ($postData['important']== 0) {
                            echo '<option value="1">مهم</option>';
                            echo '<option value="0">غير مهم</option>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<option value="0">غير مهم</option>';
                            echo '<option value="1">مهم</option>';
                        }
                ?>
            </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                حالة الظهور:<br>
                <select name="vis">
                    <?php   if ($postData['important']== 1) {
                                echo '<option value="1">ظاهر</option>';
                                echo '<option value="0">مخفي</option>';
                            } else {
                                echo '<option value="0">مخفي</option>';
                                echo '<option value="1">ظاهر</option>';
                            }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                القسم:<br>
                <select name="cat_id">
                    <?php
                        $postId = $_GET['postId'];
                        $catId = get_post_catid($postId);
                        cats_list_selected($catId);
                    ?>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                اسم المستخدم:<br>
                <select name="user_id">
                    <?php
                        $postId = $_GET['postId'];
                        $userId = get_post_userid($postId);
                        users_list_selected($userId);
                    ?>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
              الصورة الرئيسية (390x208):<br>
                <input type="file" name="bigthumb">
            </li>
            <li>
                الصورة المصغرة (130x69):<br>
                <input type="file" name="smallthumb">
            </li>
            <li>
                مقدمة المقالة (يجب ان لا تتعدي الـ160 حرف) <br><textarea name="excerpt"><?php get_excerpt($postId)?></textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
                محتوى المقالة: <br><textarea class="ckeditor" name="content"><?php get_post($postId)?></textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="تعديل المقالة">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>

<?php
} else {
    echo 'لم يتم تحديد مقالة';
}
?>
```

This the image upload function
As usual checks extension if it's allowed it uploads it and returns the info and put them in DB

```
// Upload Image
    function upload_image($tmp,$name) {
        $ext = explode('.',$name);
        if (preg_match('~(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$~i', $name)) {
        $ext = end($ext);
        $name = time() . '.' . $ext;
        $upload_dir = 'waheeb/uploads/' . $name;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp,'/home/shadne/public_html/'.$upload_dir);
            return $upload_dir;
        } else {
            throw new ErrorException('File type not allowed');
        }
    }
```

EDIT 1

```
// Edit a post
    function edit_post($postId, $postData) {
        global $db;
        $update = array();
        foreach ($postData as $field=>$data) {
            $update[] = '`' . $field . '` = \'' . $data . '\'';
        }
        $insertData = 'UPDATE `posts` SET '. implode(', ',$update) .'WHERE `post_id` =' .$postId;
        try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($insertData);
        $stmt->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e.getMessage.'Can\'t edit post');
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, what is the problem again ?

Comment: it issues an error if no image is set, i want to remove that so that it will continue even if no image is set

Comment: You mean if no file is uploaded, it thows an error ? What is the exact text of the error.

Comment: @ExpertSystem die('No image uploading'); if i try to delete try and catch it returns the error from upload_image function which is file type not allowed

Comment: Have you tried echoing `$name` in `upload_image()` to see what value is passed and makes it throw an error ?

Comment: No i didn't, didn't occur to me to do so.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30163/discussion-between-expert-system-and-saeb-msarwa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what ever reason, it seems that, even when not uploading a file, the `$_FILES` array gets populated with arrays containing empty strings. So, both `$_FILES["bigthumb"]` and `$_FILES["smallthumb"]` are set (as array containing empty strings). Therefore, the value passed to `upload_image()` as `$name` is `""`, which causes the error.

To fix this, you can use **[`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)** to check, for example, the "size" attribute.
Try replacing:

```
...
if(isset($_FILES['bigthumb'], $_FILES['smallthumb'])) {
...
```

with:

```
...
if (!empty($_FILES["bigthumb"]["size"]) 
        && !empty($_FILES["smallthumb"]["size"])) {
...
```

Comment: It writes to the DB null values.
What reason(s) that might be? if you could guess, but its not from my code right? thanks for trying.

Comment: Actually, the code that you posted does not do any writing to or reading from a DB. If I don't see any code, I cannot guess why the values are null. At least, is the error the mention in your question fixed ?

Comment: Yes, error is fixed, what code are you referring to? the image uploading process? it's the last function above.

Comment: What DataBase are you referring to ? The only operation performed to the uploaded files is **[`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)**, which moves the files in a different folder (nothing DB-related).

Comment: In which columns does it insert null values ? In all columns ?